# Chrome browser option to stop navigate to check point page for sign up funtion automation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating facebook sign up function on chrome browser. Then click on sign up button, the page navigates to the email confirmation page and suddenly it navigates to "We want to make sure that your account is secure" this page. Is there a way to stop navigating this page, please?.

Comment: You can use the facebook api for the login. [facebook Auth API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: I want to do UI automation.Thanks

Comment: Does this happen only when you use selenium and not when manually using the browser.

Comment: It happens in both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please focus on below parameters to avoid security message, "**We want to make sure that your account is secure**"*

*1. During sign up, you shall provide realistic data which makes sense*

*2. Use case, where account was not created but data was filled up in registration form and Use of exactly/kind of same data frequently land you in the problem you facing*

*3. Too much Sign up attempt in a short time span*

***Note - We have control over only data. There is no such settings available for you which can be changed before account confirmation, suspicious data/attempt would cause the problem as mentioned above.***

[image]